# Why am I getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module name "pyperclip"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm receiving this error although it works fine in the idle shell?
I am currently working through the Automate The Boring Stuff book.
I tried to search for which directory it was saved to but when I reach `c:\users\Jibby\appdata\local\programs\python` the only thing in the python folder is a folder named `mu`.

Edit: Apologies for not going into more detail, I already have it installed > I get this message when I try to pip install it again `"Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in c:\users\jibby\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.8.2)"`
It's just that when I try to run a batch file using an import pyperclip statement, it refuses to acknowledge that I have it installed. That's what I was trying to show in the Error Code photo by showing it imports fine in the IDLE shell but doesn't work when trying to run said batch file.

My error:

[image]

Comment: Have you installed pyperclip?

Comment: Yes I have, I edited my original question to include more info. When I try run a batch file it gives me an error message saying there is no module found.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `pyperclip` from cmd with

```
pip install pyperclip
```

Be sure to read [Appendix A](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/appendixa/) for how to install third party modules (including `pip`)

Comment: Apologies I didn't specify well enough but I have it installed already. I tried to install it in the scripts folder after googling elsewhere for an answer and I receive the message "Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in c:\users\jibby\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.8.2)"
It just refuses to acknowledge I have it installed when I try run a batch file.

Comment: How did you install it to the scripts folder?

Comment: I didn't, I tried to see if it would work if I installed it directly in the scripts folder but alas I received the message above. Apologies I'm not very knowledgeable with this.

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed it on the version of python that you are using?

Comment: Nevermind! I got it to work by typing in "py -m pip install pyperclip" into the cmd line

Answer (score 0):

try to type into the command promt:
"pip install pyperclip"

https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by typing in "py -m pip install pyperclip" into the command line.